# discord.py не могу сделать выбор в слэш команде

Tags: discord.py

[image: хочу сделать подобное в своём боте но не знаю как]

Хочу сделать подобное в своём боте, но не где не могу найти код, решение, лазил в документации и тоже не нашёл(( пытался сделать через Option и Optional, но пишет, что не может найти данный аргумент. Заранее очень признателен